# Need help forwarding html form content to public http service

Tags: php, javascript, html

I need help forwarding html form content to public http service if someone can explain how this can be done or where to find a tutorial for this would be great!

I have my form made as you can see below:

```
<span class="text"> <input class="text" type="text" name="First" value="First" ></span>
                <span class="text"> <input class="text" type="text" name="Last" value="Last" ></span>
                <span class="text"><input type="text" value="Email" /></span>
                <input class="btn-submit" type="submit" value="Submit"  />
```

I was given the following code to forward the input:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.saddleback.com/Services/Subscription/Subscription/Save/' + subscriptionId,
    data: {
        'firstName': firstName,
        'firstName': firstName,
        'lastName': lastName,
        'email': email,
        'redirectToUrl': redirectToUrl,
        'redirectFailureToUrl': redirectFailureToUrl
    },
    type: "post",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (message) {
        $('.subscriptionWarning').append("<span id=''litStatus''>" + message + "</span>");
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $('.subscriptionWarning').append("<span id=''litStatus''>Error encountered while saving subscription.</span>");
    }
});
```

The ID I needed to forward it to is 23

Thank you for the help and sorry if my question was phrased wrong.

```
    <span class="text"> <input class="text" type="text" name="firstName" value="First" ></span>
                <span class="text"> <input class="text" type="text" name="lastName" value="Last" ></span>
                <span class="text"><input type="text" name="email" value="Email" /></span>
                <input class="btn-submit" type="submit" value="Submit"  />       








$fname = $_GET['firstName'];
$lname = $_GET['lastName'];
$email = $_GET['email'];

$h = curl_init();

curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_URL,           "http://profile.purposedriven.com/managesubscriptionssimple.aspx");
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
'name' => 'yes',
'comment' => 'no'
));
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($h);
echo $result;
```

Thats what my code looks like now.

Comment: are you trying to submit the form to a different website?

Comment: Yes to http://profile.purposedriven.com/managesubscriptionssimple.aspx

Comment: wait... what site are you trying to submit this form to?

Comment: We are trying to submit a form from our dev site, to the form located here - http://profile.purposedriven.com/managesubscriptionssimple.aspx by passing the information through on the backend.

Our dev site is PHP while the site that the information needs to be passed to is aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to make an ajax request to an website with a different domain.

Read more here: [Why Cross-Domain AJAX call is not allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383045/why-cross-domain-ajax-call-is-not-allowed)

How ever you can make the request in your own server using php and [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

**Example:** Submit your form in your own website than:

```
$fname = $_GET['firstName'];
$lname = $_GET['lastName'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
```

And follow cURL from the manual [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php#102885)

Comment: I wrote the following code and it pulls the form off the 2nd website and posts it on rick warren.veracitycolab.com

Comment: <?php 
$fname = $_GET['firstName'];
$lname = $_GET['lastName'];
$email = $_GET['email'];

$h = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_URL, "http://profile.purposedriven.com/managesubscriptionssimple.aspx"); 
  curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
  'name' => 'yes',
  'comment' => 'no'
  ));
  curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  $result = curl_exec($h);
  echo $result;
?>

Comment: <span class="text"> <input class="text" type="text" name="firstName" value="First" ></span>
                    <span class="text"> <input class="text" type="text" name="lastName" value="Last" ></span>
                    <span class="text"><input type="text" name="email" value="Email" /></span>
                    <input class="btn-submit" type="submit" value="Submit"  />